# Attribute error while using the stackoverflow api wrapper for python on IDLE

Tags: feature-request, api, python

This is the code that I use to access Stack Overflow:

```
from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow
so = stackexchange.StackOverflow()
for q in so.questions(pagesize=50):
    print q.title
```

It runs fine when I copy and paste it on the command shell. But running it in IDLE gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\NLP\metastack.py", line 3, in <module>
    from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow
  File "C:\Users\Animesh\Desktop\stackexchange.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StackOverflow'
```

How should I correct it?

Comment: Do you have a `stackexchange.py` file in your local directory? Test with `import stackexchange; print `stackexchange.__file__`.

Comment: Which Python wrapper are you using?